# CKAN user login using API

Tags: api, drupal, ckan

I have two websites. one built using [Drupal](http://drupal.org) and the other using [CKAN](https://ckan.org)

I don't have any experience in dealing with CKAN. What I want to do is when the user login on the Drupal site, automatically login on the CKAN site.

So I'm asking, is there an API on the CKAN for making the user login or something like this?

Comment: [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no API to get logged on the CKAN. You could make one or check for an [extension](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/tutorial.html) for this kind of functionality

Comment: +1. In particular, implementing the [`IAuthenticator`](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/extensions/plugin-interfaces.html#ckan.plugins.interfaces.IAuthenticator) interface is probably the way to go.